# Serialising dictionary to XML

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary, xml-serialization, object-model

I need to generate the following XML exactly. Note that each input element has to be a string or a boolean.

```
<Userdata version="1.00">
   <ISKeyValueList>
      <Item type="String" key="AgeOfDependents">8,6,1<Item/>
      <Item type="Boolean" key="SecuritiesInPosession"> True </Item>
      <Item type="Boolean" key="SecuritiesOwners"> True </item>
   </ISKeyValueList>
</Userdata>
```

I can generate most of the above XML correctly except for the input elements. My current method generates the following:

```
<Item type="String" key="AgeOfDependents"/>
```

As you can see the Item element does not contain the text value 8,6,1.

I am currently serialising the data using the following:

**Object Model**

```
public class finClient
{
    [XmlAttribute("version")]
    public string version = "1.00";
    public UserData Userdata;
}

public class UserData
{
    [XmlAttribute("version")]
    public string version = "1.00";
    public List<Item> ISKeyValueList;
}

public class Item
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string type;
    [XmlAttribute("key")]
    public string key;
}
```

**C#**

Here is how I construct the object that I later serialise into XML

```
 Userdata = new UserData()
 {
    ISKeyValueList = new List<Item>()
    {
        new Item()
        {
           type = "String", key = "AgeOfDependents"
        }
    }   
 }
```

I am aware that adding another element e.g Value to the Item object in the object model would allow me to store these values however this would add another element into the XML which won't help as the XML needs to be exactly the same as shown at the very top.

My research into this issue has lead to beleive that I need to use a dictionary.Am I correct in thinking that I require a dictionary? If so how do I go about serialising a dictionary through the object model.

Much thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. Note that even though this question is ostensibly about XML serialization, you don't show any code that actually serializes any data! Also, there's nothing in your code example that suggests the presence of any text or other values reading "8,6,1". Why _would_ you expect that to show up in the XML?

Comment: thats what i'm trying to add. I have not provided the code that serialises the data because there is no issue with that code. The issue is with the object model.

Comment: So you don't care what the in-memory object type looks like? Then I'd say the answer given already should suffice. If it doesn't, then clearly you've got some details left out of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Given that your `Item` class can contain different types of primitive data, I'm going to suggest modeling it as containing an object of type [`IConvertible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) -- i.e. an object that can be converted from and to a string.  Then you can serialize that string value as the [character data](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-chardata) of each `Item` element (`8,6,1` in your example) by decorating the corresponding property with the [`[XmlTextAttribute]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute:

```
public class Item
{
    TypeCode _type = TypeCode.Empty; // When deserializing, attributes are deserialized before element values, which allows the _type to be set before the XmlValue is read.
    IConvertible _value = null;

    static TypeCode GetItemType(IConvertible value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return TypeCode.Empty;
        return value.GetTypeCode();
    }

    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public TypeCode type
    {
        get
        {
            return _type;
        }
        set
        {
            _type = value;
            if (GetItemType(_value) != _type)
                _value = null;
        }
    }

    [XmlAttribute("key")]
    public string key { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public IConvertible Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            _type = GetItemType(value);
            _value = value;
        }
    }

    [XmlText]
    public string XmlValue
    {
        get
        {
            if (_value == null)
                return null;
            return Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                _value = null;
            else
            {
                _value = (IConvertible)Convert.ChangeType(value, _type, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then the following test case:

```
        string xml = @"<Userdata version=""1.00"">
           <ISKeyValueList>
              <Item type=""String"" key=""AgeOfDependents"">8,6,1</Item>
              <Item type=""Boolean"" key=""SecuritiesInPosession""> True </Item>
              <Item type=""Boolean"" key=""SecuritiesOwners""> True </Item>
           </ISKeyValueList>
        </Userdata>
        ";

        var userdata = xml.LoadFromXML<UserData>();
        Debug.WriteLine(userdata.GetXml(true));
```

Produces the following output:

> ```
> <Userdata version="1.00">
>     <ISKeyValueList>
>         <Item type="String" key="AgeOfDependents">8,6,1</Item>
>         <Item type="Boolean" key="SecuritiesInPosession">True</Item>
>         <Item type="Boolean" key="SecuritiesOwners">True</Item>
>     </ISKeyValueList>
> </Userdata>
> ```

**Original Answer**

You can serialize a string (or other primitive or enumerated type) as the [character data](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-chardata) of an element (`8,6,1` in your example) by decorating the corresponding property with the [`[XmlTextAttribute]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute.  This allows you to add the extra `Value` property to your `Item` class like so:

```
public class Item
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string type;
    [XmlAttribute("key")]
    public string key;

    [XmlIgnore] // Do not output the list to XML directly
    public List<int> Values { get; set; }

    [XmlText]  // Instead, output the list as a comma-separated string in the XML element's text value.
    public string XmlValue
    {
        get
        {
            if (Values == null)
                return null;
            return string.Join(",", Values.Select(i => XmlConvert.ToString(i)).ToArray());
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                Values = null;
            else
            {
                Values = value.Split(new [] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => XmlConvert.ToInt32(s)).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then the following class:

```
var client = new finClient { Userdata = new UserData { ISKeyValueList = new List<Item> { new Item { type = "String", key = "AgeOfDependents", Values = new List<int> { 8, 6, 1 } } } } };
```

will be serialized as the following XML:

> ```
> <finClient version="1.00">
>    <Userdata version="1.00">
>       <ISKeyValueList>
>          <Item type="String" key="AgeOfDependents">8,6,1</Item>
>       </ISKeyValueList>
>    </Userdata>
> </finClient>
> ```

Comment: I actually need to add several more Item elements to ISKeyValueList e.g
<Item type="String" key="SecuritiesInPosession"> True </Item>
<Item type="Boolean" key="SecuritiesOwners"> True </item>

How can I modify your example to accept booleans and strings. I beleive that 8, 6, 1 has to be a string if you look at the type attribute.

Comment: Can you update your question to include examples of all the required XML outputs?

Comment: Done. I've added the other input elements to the XML at the beginning of my question. Thanks very much.

Comment: @CodeMonkey - answer updated (before I realized you had accepted the original answer).